# Server 2008 $Recycle.Bin has folders for non RDS users. How did that happen?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008, recycle-bin

While pruning the `$Recycle.bin` folder on a Server 2008 system, I found that there were two folders for domain users that don't have remote desktop privilege to that server.

This puzzles me as to how these folders came to be.  If they did not have remote login permission, how did they send files to the Recycle Bin?  Any file they deleted from a network share should not have gone to the server's Recycle Bin and permanently deleted instead.

These users never had remote desktop access to this box, AFAIK, so these aren't some old Recycle Bin files that they created while they had remote access, and then later had that privilege removed.

Comment: Perhaps they didnt log on remotely?  Look at the folders/files last modification date...  That might give you a clue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that these two users did in fact have Remote Desktop rights at one time, and later had that right removed.  So these Recycle Bin folders are just left overs from the days that they did work on this box.